# Authenticate ASP.NET website user with Oracle DSEE

Tags: oracle, authentication

I'm doing an ASP.NET web app, but there's a requirement that when a user enters his credentials, they are first authenticated in a Oracle DSEE 11.

So, the flow is:

- User enters credentials
- Check credentials in Oracle DSEE
- If exists, create or update user account in web app database
- If not exists, login failed

Has anyone done this that can point me in the right way?

**UPDATE**: My problem is how to authenticate with Oracle DSEE, not on general ASP.NET authentication.

Thanks

Comment: have you thought of mixing Oracle DSEE and general ASP.NET authentication?

Comment: Yes. Do you know what interfaces DSEE exposes for these purposes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [Login controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but my main problem is the middle step of checking the user's credentials with Oracle DSEE.

Comment: @theplastictoy, then why your question is tagged with `asp.net`? It seems that it has nothing to do with it. Please update it accordingly.

Comment: Well, it is an asp.net application authenticating with oracle... shouldn't it be tagged with both?

Comment: @theplastictoy, according to your first comment you already know how to deal with the first part. So try to make your question focused on a single specific topic which you are having difficulties with.